# Playing videos on all devices

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a scenario where we need to be able to play the video files in mobile devices specially on ios devices. I am using a content query WebPart to display all my videos from site assets library. I am currently using SharePoint 2010 environment.I am having mp4 and wmv video files.Could anybody suggest how to approach on this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [mediaelementjs](http://mediaelementjs.com/). Hope it will be helpfully.